# Use a function to return multiple column outputs from specific column inputs using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I would like to add two new columns to my dataframe by applying a function that takes inputs from multiple, specific pre-existing columns.

Here is my approach which works for returning one column, but not multiple:

Here is my DataFrame:

```
d = {'a': [3,0,2,2],
    'b': [0,1,2,3],
    'c': [1,1,2,3],
    'd': [2,2,1,3]}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

I'm trying to apply this function:

```
def myfunc(a,b,c):
    if a > 2 and b > 2:
        print('condition 1',a,b)
        return pd.Series((a,b))
    elif a < 2 and c < 2:
        print('condition 2',a,c)
        return pd.Series((b,c))
    else:
        print('no condition')
        return pd.Series((None,None))
```

Like this:

```
df['e'],df['f'] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['a'],x['b'],x['c']),axis=1)
```

Output:

```
no condition
no condition
condition 2 0 1
no condition
no condition
```

DataFrame result:

[image]

How can I input multiple columns and get multiple columns out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with the assignment, not `myfunc`

When you try to unpack a dataframe as a tuple, it returns the column lables.  That's why you get (0, 1) for everything

```
df['e'], df['f'] = pd.DataFrame([[8, 9]] * 1000000, columns=['Told', 'You'])
print(df)

   a  b  c  d     e    f
0  3  0  1  2  Told  You
1  0  1  1  2  Told  You
2  2  2  2  1  Told  You
3  2  3  3  3  Told  You
```

Use `join`

```
df.join(df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['a'],x['b'],x['c']),axis=1))
```

Or `pd.concat`

```
pd.concat([df, df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x['a'],x['b'],x['c']),axis=1)], axis=1)
```

both give

```
   a  b  c  d    e    f
0  3  0  1  2  NaN  NaN
1  0  1  1  2  1.0  1.0
2  2  2  2  1  NaN  NaN
3  2  3  3  3  NaN  NaN
```

Comment: Interesting, I thought about it at first but when I tested it I got two columns with NA naturally (then I thought one more magic from pandas)

Comment: This is giving me weird output. If one of the conditions is true then it populates all the values for the new columns with that output instead of 'None'.

Comment: @sparrow you'll have to update with data your actually using, this seems to work for me.  Also, note that I have `None` there.  But `pandas` will make it `NaN`

Comment: @piRSquared, Thanks, I've updated with my actual data.

Comment: @sparrow I've updated my post.  I fixed a typo of yours.

Comment: @piRSquared, returning (a,c) instead of (b,c) for condition 2 wasn't a typo. Even when I change my code to match your post exactly I still get the same results. Are you getting something different?

Comment: @sparrow whew... I think we got it now :-)  Let me know

Comment: @sparrow that is precisely the issue I addressed with my update

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice your update before I replied. deleted my comment above to avoid confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

Your function is going to return *one* series with either `NAs` or with a 2-tuple when my_funct matched.

One way to fix it is to return Series instead, that will be automatically expanded by apply:

```
def myfunc(col1,col2,col3):
    if col1 == 'x' and col2 == 'y':
        return pd.Series((col1,col2))
    if col2 == 'a' and col3 == 'b':
        return pd.Series(('yes','no'))
```

Note the double brackets to pass one argument as a tuple. A list would be fine too.

Comment: Thanks Boud, when I return as series or list I still get the same Value Error.

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong, or the problem and the df you describe in your question are not your actual reality and you have another issue

Comment: Boud, I edited my question to be more clear. If you can see what I'm doing wrong then please let me know.